# Folder redirection doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, folder-redirection

Apologies for the vague title but I really don't know why.

I've tried to set up folder redirection following the instructions on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078.aspx) word for word. Logging in on my domain creates the user profiles on each machine rather than in the Users$ directory on the server. The folder stays completely empty.

How do I even begin to troubleshoot this? The only time prior to this I had to set up Folder Redirection was using the wizard on Server 2012 Essentials which worked like a charm.

My test domain consists of 2 W7 Pro clients with a Server 2012 R2 Standard domain controller.

Comment: Standard folder redirection is not appropriate for user profile folders. You need to use the specific user profile setting: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771969.aspx

Comment: I've already done the steps described in that link. It was Step 5 in the article.

Comment: Ah wait, sorry, wrong link.

Comment: My mistake, it's step 4. I'll check over Group Policy on the server just to be sure.

Comment: Nah, my bad. I was thinking of per-user roaming profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have got Folder Redirection working. Here's what I did:

- Installed the essentials role on the server. Did Folder Redirection via the wizard.
- Went onto my client and removed the existing profiles from 'Advanced System Settings', I also removed the Registry Keys under `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/ProfileList`. (Logging in prior to this was causing logins with temporary profiles.)
- Rebooted the client VM and everything appears to be work, even though it did take 5 minutes to log in.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I even begin to troubleshoot this?

Ensure you've linked the GPO to an AD container containing the *users* you want it to apply to (it's a user-level policy, so it applies to user objects, not computer objects).

Use `GPResult` to determine if your GPO is properly applying to the users you're testing with.

Troubleshoot problems further based on GPResult's output.

Comment: It's linked to the domain. Give me a moment to check `GPResult`